# Replace cXML DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: c#, xml

I am looking to replace the DOCTYPE declaration from incoming cXML documents:

```
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.029/cXML.dtd">
```

and end up with `<!DOCTYPE cXML>`

I currently use a matching `if cXML.Contains(matching value).Replace("DOCTYPE cXML");`
the problem is that the value is variable.
Is there a wildcard option ?

Comment: In the begging you have the xml as string value ?

Comment: You can check my answer. Tell me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can you below code sample to removing and adding DOCTYPE from cXML

```
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
XDoc.Load(sXMLFile);
XmlDocumentType XDType = XDoc.DocumentType;
XDoc.RemoveChild(XDType);
```

something same for adding your DocType

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = @"<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM ""http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.029/cXML.dtd"">
                 <cXml>
                 </cXml>
                ";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var name = doc.DocumentType.Name;

var docType = new XDocumentType(name, null, null, null);

doc.DocumentType.ReplaceWith(docType);

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

You need to create new XDocumentType and after that replace the previous one.